# Null pointer exception - Service SMS with Text To Speech

Tags: java, android, service, sms, text-to-speech

I want to make an application with can say a text with a TextToSpeach when I receive a SMS.

For that I have a Service, a Receiver and a class SaidThis.

See my code :

My service :

```
package fr.dabernat.smsreceiver;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Service extends IntentService {


    private Handler handler;
    public static String text;

    public Service() {
        super("Service");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

            SaidThis test = new SaidThis();
            test.SpeakText();
            //showNotification();
            //SaidThis test = new SaidThis(this);
            //test.text("J'ai honte de moi");



        }

        Receiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

}
```

My Receiver :

```
package fr.dabernat.smsreceiver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;


public class Receiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Explicitly specify that Service will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
        Service.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }


}
```

My class SaidThis :

```
package fr.dabernat.smsreceiver;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Damien on 19/09/2014.
 */
public class SaidThis extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

    TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
           tts.setLanguage(Locale.FRANCE);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String s) {
        stopSelf();
    }

    public void SpeakText(){
        tts.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

My Android Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fr.dabernat.smsreceiver" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- A CHANGER POUR "ECOUTER" UN AUTRE BROADCAST -->
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".Service" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Errors :

```
10-08 10:44:51.980    1371-1371/fr.dabernat.smsreceiver E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
10-08 10:44:51.980    1371-1371/fr.dabernat.smsreceiver E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> fr.dabernat.smsreceiver [ userId:0 | appId:10309 ]
10-08 10:44:52.080    1371-1412/fr.dabernat.smsreceiver E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[Service]
    Process: fr.dabernat.smsreceiver, PID: 1371
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at fr.dabernat.smsreceiver.SaidThis.SpeakText(SaidThis.java:34)
            at fr.dabernat.smsreceiver.Service.onHandleIntent(Service.java:36)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I think the problem come from my service but I don't know where.
I try to find some answer on the web before but I don't find any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tts` object is not initialized anywhere, therefore it's `null`.

You have to initialize it: `tts = new TextToSpeech()` somewhere, before you use it in your `SpeakText()` method.

I assume `onInit()` method would be a good fit for initializing your object.

Comment: I try to had tts = new TextToSpeech() in the onInit() but nothing change

Comment: The `NullPointerException` was raised in the same place? Anyway, you NEED to have your object initialized, so you have to restore this `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @romainroustan Don't instantiate a service with `new`. The lifecycle methods such as `onCreate()` are not invoked.

Comment: Yeah, still have NullPointExcepction </br>FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[Service]

Comment: @romainroustan Yes, laalto actually noticed a good thing. Service should be started like this: `startService(new Intent(this, SaidThis.class));` instead of `new SaidThis()`. This, along with restoring your `onCreate()` method should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. But now I don't have any error, my tts.speak that I had in the onInit never start...